# I can't seem to figure out how to send a message to a specified user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The code I have is:

```
const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
message.delete().catch(O_o=>{}); 
message.author.send(sayMessage);
```

Instead of sending the message to the message author how do I make it send the message to a specified user?

Comment: How do you want to send the msg to the specified user - will they be tagged??

Comment: I want the member to be tagged.

Answer (score 2):

To get the user that's tagged use

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
if(!member)
    return message.reply("Please tag a valid member");
member.send("Enter Message Here");
```

Note: Using let makes it only accessible in the scope its been declared, it may be smarter to use var in your case - You may also want to remove args[0] from the say message as it's going to be the mentioned member.

Comment: I want the member to be tagged.

Comment: Okay... that’s exactly what my code does. DiscordJS uses mentions not tags or do you mean you want it to reply to the channel instead of directly to the member? You’ve left that very vague as my code does exactly what you’ve asked. Sends a message to a mentioned user.

Comment: I tried Lucy's code cause i was fiddling with a bot myself and thats exactly how its done. if you @ someone it will message them.